# Strange Page Behavior of ASP.NET Form. Request.HttpMethod is POST but Page.IsPostBack returns False

Tags: asp.net

I have strange behavior of .aspx page inside `iframe`. The first click on Submit button doesn't produce `Page.IsPostBack` and doesn't fire postback handler. The second click does. Here is the code.

**.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="form.aspx.vb" Inherits="form" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>form inside iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%--More controls--%>
            <asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class form
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            '// After first click on btnSubmit Page.IsPostBack is False
            '// and btnSubmit_Click handler isnot fired

            '// After second click on btnSubmit Page.IsPostBack is True
            '// and btnSubmit_Click handler IS fired

            '//This is a patch to work around misbehavior
            If Request.HttpMethod = "POST" Then
                btnSubmit_Click(btnSubmit, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        '//Do something
    End Sub
End Class
```

The question is mostly a warning as I already fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you get the expected behavior when not hosted in an iFrame?

Comment: surely yes. This is standard page behavior.

Comment: I suspect this relates somehow with caching.

Comment: Does the Page_Load method run on both initial page load **and** first click? I'm thinking along the lines of stale request valiation tokens etc (ie , caching as you mentioned) also are the host and child pages on the same domain/

Comment: @JonP iframe Page_Load doesn't fire in initial parent page load (which is cached). iframe Page_Load fires on the first and second click. First click... see OP.
Parent page is cached. Both pages (parent and iframe) are in the same domain.

Comment: Double-check for any javascript errors so that nothing is blocking the inbuilt client-side `__doPostBack` method. Also if you refresh the contents of the Iframe before first click do you get the expected behavior is it still broken?  If sou you may want to turn of caching with `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`